# Send mail on_behalf_of with a guest user account

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm trying to let an api send a mail on behalf of a user.

I have an UWP application (Azure AD App "A") that posts some data to the API (Azure AD App "B")

The API are then going to collect some more data and send a mail as the user that posted that data.

When the post is received by the API the bearer token has "AUD" and "SCP" for the API, now I do a request to Azure AD and swaps the token for a new one with "AUD" and "SCP" for MS Graph API. This works pretty good, until there is a guest user that sends the data. Then I get an "Unauthorized" result back from Graph API.

I assume the reason is because I get the first token as the guest user and then tries to send mail with an account in another tenant.

What can I do to bypass this?

Comment: Have you tried to use guest user object ID in tenant instead of email account ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can't send mail on_behalf_of with a guest user account because a guest user doesn't have O365 Exchange Online license in this tenant.

Although maybe the guest user has O365 Exchange Online license in its own tenant, it is not allowed to send mail from this tenant.

It is expected.

> What can I do to bypass this?

If you want the guest user to send the mail from this tenant, it's impossible.

But I think sending mail from its own tenant is not what you want and it will require you to create app registration in that tenant or use multi-tenant app. You need admin permission of that tenant to do that. So it's impossible neither.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Allen!

Now when I cooled of a bit (I have extremely hot in my work area) I realized what I tried to do and why it didnt work ;)

I'm solving the problem by looking at the bearertoken and see if it is a Guest user who uses the app and send from an "no-reply" account in those cases.